# Is a "join table" the result of a SQL JOIN, or the table between a many-to-many

Tags: sql, join, semantics

This is a question about correctly "naming things". Specifically, how do you distinguish between:

1. the "between" table in a many-to-many relationship (e.g. `users`, `users_questions`, `questions`)
2. the (temporary) table that is created during a SQL `JOIN` (e.g. 'SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN users_questions.user_id ON users.id WHERE users_question.question_id=37016694;`)

Comment: It is a table that establishes the "join" relationship between the other tables. The result of a query is a result set (and *not* a table); a temporary table / storage in a table variable / loading into a data table is different than a result set.

Comment: The first is a real table which helps to normalize your database.  The second is temporary and is not part of your actual schema.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lots of database designers use the term *join table* in your first sense: to implement a many-to-many relationship between entities. It's also called a *junction table*, *association table*, and other things.  More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

I've never heard the second sense used. (But, hey, I don't get out much. :-)  If you're writing documentation, or teaching, I suggest you reserve the word *table* to mean an actual, physical, table. Avoid using the word *table* for a resultset unless you qualify it by saying *virtual table* or some such phrase. That way your readers and students won't waste time trying to find the definitions of these not-really-tables in your schema.

Comment: I'm not even sure what he means in the 2nd sense -- he has a query with a join -- where is the temporary table?

Comment: I've most commonly heard the junction table, or the "between" table, referred to as a linking table.

Comment: I've always referred to the "between table" as being a cross reference table, sometimes prefixed by "Xref" like "Xref_User_Questions"

Comment: @Hogan . . . I think the second sense refers to the relational ideas that inner joins are subsets of the Cartesian product.  So the "join table" is the Cartesian product of the two tables and the join specifies the subsetting of the relationship.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- OK, I can buy that there is an abstract concept of a table potential in the join, but the OP mentions a table being created.  I think that is taking it a little to far -- it is conceived of not actually created.

Answer (score 0):

From relational point of view, a `JOIN` table (a table which resolves *many-to-many* relationship) *is* real physical table. Else it wouldn't survive between requests. In my opinion, the term "join table" was coined by MVC "Code First" developers who ignore physical entities in the DB realm, especially if they are not shown in DbContext.

In my opinion, again, we should honor **relational** realities.

*So help me Codd*.