# Is there a Difference between joins and link tables by workbench or is the same thing?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, join, linktable

Hello I started learning some C# and MySQL and I try making 2 or more tables to connect to each other to form a relational database.

I've looked for information and found that some people make there design in WorkBench and some using joins like I've seen in some tutorials on joins.

I am confused about some key concepts that are not very well explained. For example the difference between joins and linktables in WorkBench.

How do they work? 
Are they the same thing ? 
Is WorkBench used only for making a design pattern for a database ?

When i say Foreign Key and Primary Key and connect them is this considered as a join or it is a totally different concept and has different uses ?

Answer (score 0):

Joins, foreign keys, and primary keys are all closely-related concepts in a relational database.

The **Primary Key** uniquely identifies rows in a given table.

A **Foreign Key** denotes a *primary key* in a *different* table.

A **Join** is a way to retrieve data from multiple tables.

I haven't used SQL Workbench much, but my guess is that a link table is referring to a table containing multiple *foreign keys* to create a "many to many" relationship between two tables.

For example:

Table `User`

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    userId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(40)
);
```

Table `Post`

```
CREATE TABLE Post(
    postId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    postContents VARCHAR(max)
);
```

Table `UserPost`

```
CREATE TABLE UserPost(
    userId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(userId),
    postId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Post(postId)
);
```

The table `UserPost` would be a "link table" that links together the `User` and `Post` tables to indicate the many posts that any one user could have.

You could then find all posts of a given user with a SQL query like below, using `UserPost` to *link* together `User` and `Post`

```
SELECT u.username, p.postContents FROM User u
  JOIN UserPost up ON up.userId = u.userId
  JOIN Post p ON up.postId = p.postId
```

So in summary, a link table allows us to use joins to "join" together information from multiple tables. Because of this, link tables are more often referred to as "join tables". See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016694/is-a-join-table-the-result-of-a-sql-join-or-the-table-between-a-many-to-many) for more details about join tables.